# select 2 column id with no repeat

Tags: php, mysql

here's my code, i need to scan message history where have 2 id in the table.
my db

table : MESSAGE

```
sender,receiver,message    
1,2,helloooo    
2,1,haiii    
1,3,yoo    
2,3,yaa
1,3,sss
3,1,asd
```

current $_session['userid'] = 1

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message WHERE sender = '$userid' OR receiver = '$userid'");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($que)){
    if($data['sender'] == $userid ){
         echo $data['receiver']."<br>";
    }else{
         echo $data['sender']."<br>";
    }
}
```

and the result is :

2

2

3

3

3

how to not repeat that?

all i need is :

2

3

Comment: And what is exactly your question?

Comment: First of all, don't use mysql_* function anymore. They are deprecated. Use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: what do you mean by *"current `$_session['userid'] = 1`"* exactly? and did you start the session?

Comment: sorry, i have fix it, thanks for advise

Comment: this is failing you btw `while($data = mysql_fetch_array($que))` <<< wrong variable >>> `$query = mysql_query("SELECT...`

Comment: Second, you are using $data = mysql_fetch_array and then testing for $data['sender']. mysql_fetch_array won't give you an associative array. Use mysql_fetch_assoc for that.

Comment: $_SESSION['userid'] now store value 1

Comment: @EddeAlmeida actually, mysql_fetch_array result is also associative

Comment: sorry mybad, this my first time :)

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to remove duplicates.

Comment: @fusion3k you are right. I was mistakenly thinking of mysql_fetch_row. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do some thing like

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$ids = array(); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message WHERE sender = '$userid' OR receiver = '$userid'");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($que)){
    if($data['sender'] == $userid ){
         $ids[] = $data['receiver']
    }else{
         $ids[] = $data['sender']
    }
}
$result = array_unique($ids);
foreach ($result as $id) {
    echo $id."<br>";
}
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for helping :D